# What is the value of following limit?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, logarithms

Let $P$ be a polynomial in complex variable $z$ of degree $d$

i.e. $P(z)= a_d z^d+.....+a_1 z+a_0$

Now I want to calculate following limit

> $f(z) = \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{d^n} (Log|P(z)^{*n} - b|)$

where $b \in$$\mathbb C$ is constant and $P(z)^{*n}$ is $n$ times composition of $P$.

I tried to take roots of $P^{*n}$ under $b$ and then root decomposition but couldn’t succeed. Any hint is welcome.

Comment: I think this is a very difficult problem, even for $P(z)=z^2+c$.

Comment: Ohh I see. Shall I post it on math overflow?

Comment: Wait a few days, see what turns up here before you do that. If you eventually do that, be sure to link each question to the other.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316570/what-is-the-value-of-following-limit